# Samsung Galaxy S4 USB Not Recognized by Windows 7

Tags: usb, windows, samsung-galaxy-s-4

When I connect my Samsung Galaxy S4 (Verizon) with a USB cable to my work PC that is running Windows 7, my work PC recognizes it immediately.  I see all my pictures, music, etc.

When I connect my phone to my home PC which is also running Windows 7, I get a device named "CD Drive (F:) Verizon Mobile".  I see a very short list of folders and files that includes a USB driver (with an autorun) and a few Mac OS folders in it.  In Device Manager, this shows up under DVD/CD-ROM drives" with a driver named "SAMSUNG File-Stor Gadget USB Device".

After a few seconds of looking at  these files, Windows removes the device and replaces it with one labeled "SCH-I545".  Clicking on SCH-I545, there are no files visible.  I have many files and photos on my phone, but I can't see any of them in Explorer.  If I right-click SCH-I545 and get Proeprties, I see a battery level, but nothing else.

Opening Device Manager, I see SCH-I545 in the list of portable devices.  The manufacturer of this driver is Microsoft.  I have tried uninstalling the driver, unplugging the phone, and plugging it back in, but the same thing happens.

I have tried downloading and installing the USB driver from the Samsung site, but the same thing happens.

I have managed to get Samsung Link working to load some files onto my phone, but I would much rather use a file copy mechanism.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can get my home PC to recognize the phone and let me copy files to and from it?

Comment: What are these drivers you installed? Is it from Samsung Kies?

Comment: Most, if not all, devices are treated as CD device initally, that is to enable to install the driver from the device, once installed, it switches to another USB mode, that is, a drive with your files on it. What Android Version? What mode is it in, MTP?

Answer (score 1):

After searching the Internet for similar issues, I did the following:

1. I unplugged my phone from the USB cable.
2. On the home screen, I pressed the bottom left Settings button and chose Settings.
3. I selected "... More".
4. I pressed "Developer options" in the list below.
5. I turned on the Developer options at the top.
6. Under the Debugging section, I checked "USB debugging".
7. I reinstalled Samsung Kies.
8. I started Kies.
9. After Kies started, I plugged in my phone to the USB cable.

After connecting my phone with Kies running, the Windows Update form appeared and a new entry was in the list.  After the driver installation, everything worked.  I don't even have to run Kies first before connecting my phone to get Windows 7 to recognize it.  It just works.

I don't know exactly what series of events caused this to start working, but now I can actually copy stuff to and from my phone.  (Yay!)

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your Galaxy S4 to the PC via USB, open the notification center and you'll see a message that says something like `Connected to USB. Click for more options`. Click it, and then select `View as camera`. After that you, should be able to copy files from the PC to your phone.